# How can I limit the power fed by voltage source in DC microgrids?

Tags: power-electronics

I have voltage sources in parallel sharing the same the load. To distribute the power of the sources on the load, I'm using the droop control. An average converter model is used for power flow. How to limit the power of one voltage source regardless of droop control? Is there any solution for that?

---

thanks for your feedback. im modelling my voltage source like this: [image]. the average converter source is modelled like this:

```
component avg_dcdc_converter_var_droop
% n-Behavioral DC-DC Converter
% This block represents an n-behavioral model of a DC-DC converter
% based on the ideal transformer.
 
inputs
    vref  = { 0, 'V' };         % reference Voltage 
    Droop = { 0, 'V/A' };         %  Droop Gain
    Fault =  { 0, '1'};            % Fault
end
 
nodes
    p1 = foundation.electrical.electrical;   % 1+:left
    n1 = foundation.electrical.electrical;   % 1-:left
    p2 = foundation.electrical.electrical;   % 2+:right
    n2 = foundation.electrical.electrical;   % 2-:right
end
 
variables
    i1 = { 0, 'A' }; % Primary current
    v1 = { 1, 'V' }; % Primary voltage
    i2 = { 0, 'A' }; % Secondary current
    v2 = { 0, 'V' }; % Secondary voltage
end
 
branches
    i1 : p1.i -> n1.i;
    i2 : p2.i -> n2.i;
end
 
equations
    assert(Droop>=0)
    if Fault < 0.5
    v1 == p1.v - n1.v;
    v2 == p2.v - n2.v;
    v2 == vref + Droop * i2;
    i2 == -(v1*i1)/v2;
    else
    v1 == p1.v - n1.v;
    v2 == p2.v - n2.v;
    v2 == 0;
    i1 == 0;
    end
  
end
end
```

and im calculating the droop parameters like this:

```
function [d1,d2,d3]= fcn(Pmains,Pbat,PFuel)
 
Pbat = 0.2;
Pmains = 0.4;
PFuel = 0.4;

Ratio_main = Pmains/(Pbat+Pmains);
Ratio_bat = Pbat/(Pbat+Pmains);
Ratio_Fuel = PFuel/(Pbat+Pmains+PFuel);

d1 = 0.25/Ratio_main;
d2 = 0.25/Ratio_bat;
d3 = 0.25/Ratio_Fuel;
```

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: rafika - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it was actually more info, not a solution, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, please **don't** use the box labeled "Your Answer" below unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you don't need further help & you solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer). Instead, to add more info / clarification, please edit the question. Or *comment* to respond to an answer. || Please see the [tour] & [help]. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> how can i limit the power fed by voltage source in DC microgrids?

Certainly! When you have multiple voltage sources in parallel sharing the same load and using droop control for power sharing, there might be situations where you want to limit the power output of a particular source. This can be due to a variety of reasons such as protection, equipment limitations, or operational constraints.

To limit the power output of one voltage source regardless of droop control, you can follow these methods:

1. **Hardware Current Limiting**:

   - Most power converters (like inverters) come with hardware current limiting features to prevent damage. When the current approaches a certain limit, the converter will automatically reduce its output power.
   - This current limit ensures that even under droop control, a particular voltage source won't exceed a power rating.
2. **Software-Based Limiting**:

   - Implement a software-based control loop that constantly monitors the power (or current) output of each converter.
   - When the output approaches the desired limit, override the droop control by reducing the reference voltage set point of the converter. This will reduce the power output.
   - To ensure smooth operation, apply this override gently using control techniques like PID to prevent oscillations.
3. **Dynamic Droop Coefficient**:

   - Adjust the droop coefficient dynamically based on real-time power measurements. If the power of a particular source approaches its limit, increase its droop coefficient, making it less sensitive to load changes.
   - This will effectively cause that particular source to contribute less to the shared load while allowing other sources to compensate.
4. **Use a Secondary Control Loop**:

   - Implement a secondary control loop on top of the primary droop control. This loop monitors the output power of each source and intervenes when the power exceeds a certain threshold.
   - This intervention could be in the form of adjusting the droop coefficient or directly altering the voltage reference.
5. **Incorporate Power Limiting in the Droop Control**:

   - Modify the droop control equation itself to factor in power limits. The droop control equation is typically given by ( V_{ref} - V = m \times P ), where ( V_{ref} ) is the reference voltage, ( V ) is the actual voltage, ( m ) is the droop coefficient, and ( P ) is the output power.
   - Introduce a term that adjusts ( m ) based on the output power so that as ( P ) approaches the limit, the droop effect increases.

It's important to remember that while limiting the power output of a source, you should ensure that the overall system stability is maintained. If you suddenly cut the power contribution from one source, other sources might be forced to compensate, leading to system oscillations or instability. Implementing these power limiting techniques with care and good engineering practices will ensure a stable and reliable power distribution system.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  i have modelled my average converter for power flow as follows:equations
    assert(Droop>=0)
    if Fault < 0.5
    v1 == p1.v - n1.v;
    v2 == p2.v - n2.v;
    v2 == vref + Droop * i2;
    i2 == -(v1*i1)/v2;
    else
    v1 == p1.v - n1.v;
    v2 == p2.v - n2.v;
    v2 == 0;
    i1 == 0;The droop equations as follows: 
Ratio_main = Pmains/(Pbat+Pmains);
Ratio_bat = Pbat/(Pbat+Pmains);
Ratio_Fuel = PFuel/(Pbat+Pmains+PFuel); do you have any suggestion of what can i modify?

Comment: the idea that iwant to monitor the power in 1kW regardless the droop control. so when the power exceeds the desired limitation, the droop control should not work

Comment: in the normal operation v2 == vref + Droop * i2; should i cange this equation in the converter dynamic when the power exceeds 1kW if so how i can i implement it?

Answer (score 1):

> do you have any suggestion of what can i modify?

Based on your provided model equations, it seems you're defining the behavior of two voltage sources (v1 and v2) under normal and fault conditions. The droop control is being implemented for v2 using the relation v2 == vref + Droop * i2.

1. **Droop Control**:

   - Use the equation `v2 == vref + Droop * i2` for your droop control.
   - To limit the power of `v2` to a value `P_limit`, adjust either `vref` or `Droop` if `v2 * i2` nears `P_limit`.
2. **Power Sharing Ratios**:

   - Adjust `Ratio_main`, `Ratio_bat`, and `Ratio_Fuel` dynamically based on power limits or thresholds.
3. **Power Limiting**:

   - Implement: `if v2 * i2 > P_limit: adjust vref or Droop`.
4. **Dynamic Droop Coefficient**:

   - Make `Droop` variable based on power: `Droop = f(v2 * i2)`, where `f()` is a function representing the relationship.
5. **Feedback Control**:

   - Monitor the output power and adjust `vref` or `Droop` values dynamically to maintain limits.

Make sure to test the model after each modification for system stability!

Comment: if v2 * i2 > P_limit: adjust vref or Droop. how much vref or droop should be. as i have the bus voltage is  vref=350V and i want power limitation at 1kW.

Comment: Calculate:

1. **Determine Current Limit**: 
\[ i2_{limit} = \frac{1kW}{350V} \]
  
2. **Adjustment**:
If \( v2 \times i2 \) exceeds 1kW:
- Reduce `vref` slightly (e.g., by 1V).
- Or, increase the `Droop` value a bit.

3. **Feedback Control**:
Monitor \( v2 \times i2 \) and adjust `vref` or `Droop` based on the deviation from 1kW.